# Repeating group headers on each page of a report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a group header that I'm trying to repeat on each page (if the detail rows for that instance of a group span onto more than one page)

For example, if I have food items in a store, and I group them by category and I use the category as a header I'll get a report like this

**Vegetables**

Peppers

Carrots

**Meat**

Chicken

Beef

.

.

.

Etc.

If the listing for one of the categories goes onto a second page, I would want the category header to repeat. So if the instance of the group goes onto a second page I want the header of that group to repeat on each page.

The setup I have in reporting services is like this:

[image]

The red circle are the rows of the table I'm trying to get to repeat on each page.

Is this possible to do? And if so, how do I do it?

I have already tried setting the two rows circled to have "KeepWithGroup = After" and "RepeatOnNewPage = "True" and I set the Tablix as a whole to have "Repeat header rows on each page" checked off.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the following website;

http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2010/06/14/what-to-do-when-the-repeatcolumnheaders-property-in-a-tablix-isn-t-working.aspx

Helped me a few times when group-headers where not repeating.

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work, thanks though.