# To repeat group header on each page of SSRS 2005 report

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have SSRS 2005 report with a group header consisting of report parameter and an image.I want this header to be repeated on each page of the the report.I have set RepeatOnNewPage property to true , checked repeat header rows on each page option in tablix properties and checked Repeat group header option in grouping properties.Still i am not getting this header repeated on every page of report.Is there any way wherein i can get the desired output?

Comment: Also asked here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128009/repeating-group-headers-on-each-page-of-a-report   no answer there either.   Maybe it can't be done.

Comment: Have you went into **Advanced mode** and changed the settings for the Header to RepeatOnNewPage **True** and KeepWithGroup **After**? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285923/tablix-repeat-header-rows-on-each-page-not-working-report-builder-3-0

Comment: @Hannover Fist I think the option of the advanced mode is not present in SSRS 2005.It is with SSRS 2008 and higher